# Как отобразить свое приложение поверх другого?

Tags: android

Хочу сделать нечто похожее на картинку в картинке, появляющуюся по ресиверу, даже когда приложение закрыто, но что бы поддерживались более старые версии Android. Недолгим гуглением узнал о каком-то "наложении", существующем начиная с SDK 23, но при попытке узнать поподробнее гугл выдает только информацию об исправлении ошибки "обнаружены наложения".
Как создать это наложение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся необходимая информация оказалась здесь https://habr.com/company/skbkontur/blog/243063/
Если кратко, то, используя android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, можно создать WindowManager с View внутри поверх любого приложения.